# Как получить разницу в минутах между двумя Date?

Tags: java, время

У меня есть два объекта `Date`

Мне требуется вычислить между ними разницу в минутах

Comment: Какими способами уже пробовали это сделать? Какие возникли проблемы?

Comment: вычитание `.getTime()` даст разницу в миллисекундах

Comment: @zolt  вычитал разницу между двумя объектами с помощью `.getTime()`, а миллисекунды пытался перевести методом `long duration= TimeUnit.MICROSECONDS.toMinutes(mills)` но результат все время 0, какой использовать для перевода из миллисекунд в секунды?
@StrangerintheQ

Comment: если версия Java 8+, то можно попробовать `Duration.between(date1.toInstant(), date2.toInstant()).seconds`

Comment: сделайте ваш `(Date1.getTime()-Date2.getTime())/1000/60`

Comment: @sakuraso13 деление на 1000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если с использованием `java.time` из Java 1.8 то можно так:

```
startDate.toInstant().until(endDate.toInstant(), ChronoUnit.MINUTES);
```